# How to access instance class of a test method when using Nunit action attributes?

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, decorator

I'm trying to create a simple decorator that'll take a screenshot when a test fails.

I have the following I'm using as a base class, so there's an easy to reference instance of the webdriver that's associated with the test.

```
public class SeleniumBaseTest {
    public IWebDriver Driver;

    public IWebDriver NewWebdriver() {
       Driver = WebDriverFactory.NewDriver();
       return Driver;
    }

    public void TakeScreenShot() { 
        //code to take screenshot.
    }
}
```

So so far, I've been able to create a decorator to perform actions after a test fails.  However I haven't figured out how to get the current test class instance so I can get the webdriver associated.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class ScreenShotOnError: Attribute, ITestAction
{

    public void BeforeTest(TestDetails details)
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    public void AfterTest(TestDetails details)
    {
        switch (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status)
        {
            case TestStatus.Failed:
            case TestStatus.Inconclusive:
                var context = TestContext.CurrentContext;
                Console.WriteLine("Test failed hook running.");
                Console.WriteLine(context);
                // I need to figure out how to access the test instance.
                // _SeleniumBaseTestInstance.TakeScreenShot();
                break;
        }
    }


    public ActionTargets Targets
    {
        get { return ActionTargets.Test; }
    }
}
```

Usage of this base test and the decorator would be like,

```
[TestFixture]
class FtwWebScreenShotTestActionTest:SeleniumBaseTest 
{

    [Test]        
    [ScreenShotOnError]
    public void Test()
    {
        var driver = NewWebdriver();
        // perform test actions
    }

}
```

Please help me figure out how I can access the containing class from a method decorator.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the details contain the TestFixture, which is the instance of the class I wanted.

```
 public void AfterTest(TestDetails details)
        {
            switch (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status)
            {
                case TestStatus.Failed:
                case TestStatus.Inconclusive:
                    try
                    {
                        (details.Fixture as SeleniumBaseTest).TakeScreenShot();
                    }
                    catch (NullReferenceException)
                    {
                        throw new TypeAccessException("This decorator should only be used with {0}" + typeof(SeleniumBaseTest).Name);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: although, I do still like to know how I can access a decorated method's context for a few other decorators I would like to write.